# How can i use @defer for Lazy loading in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-directive, angular-lazyloading

I saw recently that in **Angular 17** you can simplify lazy loading by using the `@defer` directive. I'm wondering how to use it exactly to refactor my old code. Today I need to use the router for that but i don't really need it anymore, right?

Let say i have an Angular app with a 2nd `router-outlet` inside a component to display different content depending on a left menu. The content displayed come from others standalone components. My angular 16 code base for my component look like:

*top.component.html*

```
<div id="leftMenu">
    <div (click)="loadContent('sub-a')">Button1</div>
    <div (click)="loadContent('sub-b')">Button2</div>
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

*top.component.ts*

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-top',
    templateUrl: './top.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./top.component.scss'],
    standalone: true,
    imports: [RouterOutlet]
})
export class TopComponent {

  constructor(private router: Router) {}
  
  loadContent(destination:string){
    this.Router.navigate(['top', destination]);
  }

}
```

*top.routes.ts*

```
import { Routes } from "@angular/router";

export default [{
  path: '',
  loadComponent: () => import('./top.component').then(m=>m.TopComponent),
  children:[
    {
      path: 'sub-a', 
      loadComponent: () => import('./subA/sub-a.component').then(m=>m.SubComponentA)
    },
    {
      path: 'sub-b', 
      loadComponent: () => import('./subB/sub-b.component').then(m=>m.SubComponentB)
    }
  ]
}] as Routes;
```

How can i use `@defer` to simplify that?

Comment: I don't think `@defer` is for routing. `loadComponent: ()` is still the way to go for that. `@defer` is for when you're directly including a heavy component in a template and want to defer its load until some point.

Comment: Ok, i get that. But i use the router by default to build a lazyloading architecture. I don't really need it in that case

Answer (score 2):

Deferrable view, defined with the `@defer` block is a declarative API to specify that a component is a template should be loaded later.

It's not here to replace router based lazy-loading but more a complement when there is no specific route the deferred component.

The best example is a heavy component on a scrolled page.